# How to reduce amount written to mongod.log

Tags: mongodb, logging

I have Mongo 2.0.3 installed on RHEL5, and have a lot of data being written to the /var/log/mongod.log file. It seems that every query, insert, update etc is written fully. I imagine this is hurting performance.

I just double-checked that I have disabled verbose logging:

```
> db.adminCommand({setParameter:1, logLevel:0});
{ "was" : 1, "ok" : 1 }
> db.adminCommand({setParameter:1, quiet:true});
{ "was" : true, "ok" : 1 }
```

In my mongo.conf I have:

```
# v = 1
quiet = true
profile=1
```

Could it be something to do with slow query logging? How else can I disable file-based logging or at least reduce verbosity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling profiling or at least increase the threshold to a reasonable high value.
See [Database Profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler).

Comment: Hmmm.. just checked this. I had level=1 and > 100ms. I've just set it to 200ms to set what happens.