# mongodb:close log out in mongod

Tags: javascript, c, mongodb

I've started `mongodb` on my machine and the log goes to `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`.
When I execute any query/insert/delete/update the operation is logged to that file too.

How can I supress these messages? I've change the configuration file and set following values:

```
verbose=v
quiet=true
```

but they don't work, I still got verbose logging in logfile.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using profiler (profile option in configuration file)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reduce amount written to mongod.log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601968/how-to-reduce-amount-written-to-mongod-log)

Comment: @madhead yes,I used profiler,because mongod printed there's profiler.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove or comment out (with a '#') the config entry for `verbose=v`.  Your setting of one `v` is equivalent to increased log messaging at level 1 (each extra `v` will increase the detail of logging).

The [default verbose level](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#verbose) is "false", which will be less verbose.

Comment: I set following values: verbose=true v=true . mongod back me this error: unknown option v

Comment: `v` is a value for `verbose`, not a separate config file option.  If you don't want verbose logging you need to remove this line or comment it out eg: `# verbose=v`.